# Excel 2010 VBA - Calculate average based on name in Column A

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to excel VBA and I've been searching for a few hours and I can't figure this out.  The `R1C1` method is confusing me (I have been researching it), but this is how the `record macro` started the formula.

I have names in `Column 1` and I need to `average` all the values in `Column 4`, but only for each `Name`, then repeat for the other names.  I want the output in `Column 5`, Offset(0,1) from "Buy Day".  I have been searching online and putting together some code from other examples I found, but I still can't get it.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

**Example Sheet (note: is there any way to insert a table?)**

[image]

**Desired Outcome**

[image]

**Code (so far)**

```
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long
Dim lNoRows As Long

LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D" & LastRow2)
lNoRows = rng.Rows.Count

For r1 = 1 To lNoRows
    If rng(r1, 4) = "Buy Day" Then
        For r2 = 1 To lNoRows
            If rng(r1, 1) = rng(r2, 1) And r1 = r2 Then _
                rng(r2, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R" & r2 & "C[-1]:R" & r2 & "C[-1])"
        Next r2
    End If
Next r1

Range("K9").FormulaR1C1 = "=Average(R[-7]C[-7]:R[1]C[-7])"
```

Basically what I'm trying to recreate in the top Average formula is what's in the bottom one, except dynamically, not specific to one cell.  When it runs right now it just pulls in one value, it doesn't do any averaging.  In cell E6 it shows `=AVERAGE(D$5:D$5)`.

Comment: can you show a screen shot of how you want your data to look like after running the macro? also, when you say `Row 1` are actually referring to `Column` somehow. it is confusing.

Comment: ...wow I see I noobed up a bunch of words.  Yes, give me a few minutes and I will update it so it makes sense.

Comment: ok i get it. And you only want this done via VBA? cause it think it is possible with just a formula. im not sure but i really think it is.

Comment: Yes, it's part of a larger macro that I'm working on so I'd really like to have it be completed via VBA.  The first part of my macro is much simpler though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've understood that you've mixed up rows and columns in your question description. So I'll just show you the idiomatic Excel way of doing what you want:

[image]

You'll find the Subtotal tool in Data > Outline > Subtotal.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even know that was there.  Hmm, I'm trying this out right now.  (Although I still really want to get it working in VBA, but I also want to learn this option).  I also just found out about the "Clear Outline" option, which is pretty cool too.

Comment: @ZubaZ - yeah, Excel is full of these surprises. Often, and I think in this case too, you can record a macro while carrying out a simple subtotal as above, and then adapt the macro (copy results to an output worksheet, delete 'scratch' worksheet, etc.) to your larger data set. No need to 'code by hand'.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't answered a question twice before, but I feel that even though my first answer is still valid, *this* one is better. You will want this formula in your cell E2, and then copy down for the entire column:

```
=IF(D2 = "Buy Day", AVERAGEIF($A:$A, A2, $D:$D), "")
```

It takes the average of only those numbers in column D whose corresponding symbol in column A is the same as the symbol in the 'Buy Day' row. It will give you your desired outcome.

Comment: :D  Thanks!  I ended up getting to a very similar ending after many, many trial and error attempts.  I actually used AVERAGEIFS (after finding out about that on another question).